# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to make a cli app with python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

Python newbie here. I wanna make a CLI tool with python. It was working before when I had everything in one large file, but now that i've organized the code, it's not working anymore.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
rails_updater/
|- build/
|--rails_updater/
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- app_generator.py
|  |- cli.py
|  |- updater.py
|- README.md
|- setup.py
```

There are more files inside of the `rails_updater/rails_updater/` but they're unnecessary to show. Note that `cli.py` is like the main file.

Here is my `setup.py`. Again, I'm omitting unnecessary info.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='rails updater',
    py_modules=[
       'rails_updater.cli',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [ 
            'rails-updater = rails_updater.cli:main' 
        ] 
    },
)
```

then I run:

```sh
python setup.py build
```

and then

```sh
pip install .
```

And everything seems to build/install fine. However, when I try running in the terminal `rails-updater`, I get this error:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rails_updater.updater'
```

---

It's probably worth mentioning that my `__init.py__` file is empty. In my `cli.py` file, i'm importing updater like this:

```py
from updater import Updater
```

Any idea on why this isn't working?

Comment: Can't you just do `packages=find_packages()` and let that do its job finding all packages? You're clearly just specifying `rails_updates.cli` in your module list, so the other modules ought to be missing.

Comment: does your find_package loads rail_updater correctly?

Comment: @michalwa thanks for the response! If I use `packages=find_packages()`, then can i remove the `py_modules` block from my setup.py file?

Comment: Yes, @AngelGarcia. From what I know, `py_modules` and `packages` are mutually exclusive in terms of usage.

Comment: @michalwa Yep that worked! thanks so much! I remembering following a blog article to import that find_packages method and it never used it haha. If you'd like to leave an answer, I can give you the green checkmark

Comment: It's alright. Glad I could help.